# Send diff output to 3 files

Tags: bash, diff, file-descriptor

What I want to do is, diff 2 files and write the diff output to 3 different files.
I can tell diff to format its output like:

```
diff a.txt b.txt --new-line-format=... --old-line-format=... --unchanged-line-format=...
```

And using this:

```
diff a.txt b.txt --new-bla-bla="echo %l>new.txt" --old--="echo %l>old" ...
```

I can output to 3 different files, except the double quotes don't appear.
I want to do this as minimally as possible, so running 3 diffs, etc are not an option

Comment: Why do you want to `eval` the output? From your example, it seems `./myProgram --format='%l'` would give the the same result as the `eval`. More detail would help, but this sounds a little like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @chepner There you go,.. I am interested in the attempted solution btw, I have solved the actual problem, I am just trying to shorten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that is maybe a little longer, but more robust as it avoids the need for `eval`:

```
diff a.txt b.txt --new-line-format "3 %L" \
                 --old-line-format "4 %L"\
                 --unchanged-line-format "5 %L" |\
   while read -r fd line; do
     echo "$line" >&$fd
   done 3> new.txt 4> old.txt 5> unchanged.txt
```

This works by prefixing each of the new, old, and unchanged lines (respectively) with the file descriptor of the file we will add them to. We then parse the output using `read`, and echo the line to the correct file descriptor, each of which is redirected to the correct output file.

Comment: Good one. In my solution, I marked the beginning of the lines, then iterated over them once. The file descriptiors make it faster for sure.

Comment: as an extra note, I was able to put multiple echo commands into the --format field and have the same line output to multiple files. How can I do the same using your solution? I think I'll have to use 'tee' but I don't know how that can combile with a file descriptor

Comment: I added a few notes, but I forgot to send you a notification. Check my previous comment please

Comment: One thought is to tag each line with something like "3;4", then split `fd` into an array using `IFS=; read -a fds <<< $fd` (we're getting pretty bash-specific now, if you don't mind), and finally something like `for fd in "${fds[@]}"; do echo "$line" >&$fd; done`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following before I read @chepner's excellent answer:

```
diff diff_old diff_new --new-line-format='>%L' --old-line-format='<%L' --unchanged-line-format='=%L' |  
awk '
    function printto(file) {print substr($0,2) > file} 
    /^>/ {printto("new.txt")} 
    /^</ {printto("old.txt")} 
    /^=/ {printto("unchanged.txt")}
'
```

This works silimarly to his answer but requires another process instead of working in the current[*] shell.

[*] discounting the subshell created for the while commands in a pipeline.